# Transfer String Array Contents with limited number of contents to new String Array from last Array position

Tags: c#, arrays, string, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have String array named "string_array_packet" which contains

FA,6,52,4C,0,A4,FA,6,52,4C,0,A4,FA,6,52,4C,0,A4,FA,6,52,4C,0,A4,FA,6,52,4C,0,A4,FA,6,52,4C,0,A4,FA,6,52,4C,0,A4,FA,6,

Now i need to check for the existence of the contents "FA,6,52,4C,0,A4,"(Which is the correct response) from the end of Array(string_array_packet) to another string array . In the above array content correct response starts from string_array_packet[Length-8] considering FA is the start byte for every response. But the index position may vary since the array content is dynamically getting generated. I am trying the following but i know it won't work if the position changes. Any help would be much appreciated

```
    string_array_packet[string_array_packet.Length - 8]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following.

```
var strArray = new string[]{"FA","6","52","4C","0","A4","FA","6","52","4C","0","A4","FA","6","52","4C","0","A4","FA","6","52","4C","0","A4","FA","6","52","4C","0","A4","FA","6","52","4C","0","A4","FA","6","52","4C","0","A4","FA","6"};
var searchArray = new string[]{"FA","6","52","4C","0","A4"};
var index = strArray.FindAllIndexOf("FA")
                    .Reverse() 
                    .First(x=>strArray
                                .Skip(x)
                                .Take(searchArray.Count())
                                .SequenceEqual(searchArray));
var result = strArray.Skip(index).Take(searchArray.Count());
```

Where FindAllIndexOf is defined as

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static int[] FindAllIndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, T val)
    {
        return values.Select((b,i) => object.Equals(b, val) ? i : -1)
                     .Where(i => i != -1)
                     .ToArray();
    }
}
```

This would give output as

```
index : 36
result : FA,6,52,4C,0,A4
```